# How to export into Excel with openrowset function

Tags: sql, sql-server, openrowset, aceoledb

I am trying to export a table into Excel through `Openrowset` command

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET 
   ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
   'Excel 12.0;Database=c:\Test.xls;','SELECT * FROM dbo.tablename')
```

I am getting an error :

> 'incorrect syntax near )'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export into an Excel:

You can use three common file formats to export SQL Server data to Excel:

- Excel workbook (`XLS`/`XLSX` file).

> **Note :** Only *SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services)* supports exporting to Excel workbook.
>
> **Note :** *SQL Server Express Edition* not allows to save a SSIS package so you can use this way only if you have *SQL Server Standard* or higher.

[Read this article :] [SQL Server Export to Excel using SSIS](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-ssis.htm).

---

- `CSV` file.

Microsoft Excel users can open `CSV` file the same way as a native Excel file.

So export to `CSV` files is suitable for most cases and you can use a simple command line utilities instead of SQL Server Integration Services.

The disadvantage of the export to Excel workbook or `CSV` file is that a user receives a new file every time and losts its changes.

[Read this article :] [SQL Server Export to Excel using bcp/sqlcmd and CSV](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-bcp-sqlcmd-csv.htm).

---

- `XML` file.

`XML` can be more suitable as a user can import `XML` file to an Excel workbook once and then refresh the data when get a new file.

[Read this article :] [SQL Server Export to Excel using bcp/sqlcmd and XML](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-bcp-sqlcmd-xml.htm).